# how to use the generated c code from the Matlab coder, in Visiual Studio 2013

Tags: c, matlab

I have generated a standalone c code using matlab coder. As it is described in the video presented in the mathwork, I think I have generated a correct static lib c code. I have added an externally defined c code to the function using coder.ceavl function. However after generating the code I tried to test it using Visual Studio 2103. But I've got some LNK type errors saying the externally attached c function is not defined or something like that. 
I want to know the correct procedure how to use the generated code after the matlab coder software. ex: implementing the code in VS.
plz help.
thanks

Comment: You may want to #include all the headers if some are missing. This is basically what this error means. (BTW, _linker errors_)

Comment: thnks. But do i have to add additional dependencies and other libraries using Link->input in project properties??

Comment: I have actually never used the MATLAB coder. I just read the post and see that you have a linker error. This error looks as if you have missing headers or function definition. This externally defined function need to (a) be declared and implemented in a header file, (b) declared in a header and implemented in a .c file. This is called the "One Definition Rule" (ODR). Either you have used unincluded c functions in the code or defined your external funciton incorrectly. Since you have done this by yourself I cannot help more without knowing what you did.

Comment: Thanks Patrik, I'll check that again. But I started to code my self because it is better to have a try by myself.